# Runtime Error - Code for generating a array of prime numbers

Tags: c, algorithm

**Code for generating a array of prime numbers**

I have written the code in c language I want the code to generate prime number till `10^9`

```
long primes[100000];
long number;
void prime_array_generator(long max){
    long sqrprime=9;
    long y=4,p=2;

    long testnumber=4,k,l=2;
    int j=0; 
    long n=1;   
    while(1){
        if(sqrprime>max){
            sqrprime = max;
        }
        for(;testnumber<=sqrprime;testnumber++){
            for(k=0;k<l;k++){
                if(testnumber%p==0){
                    j=1;
                    break;
                }
                p = primes[k+1];
            }       
            if(j==1){
                j=0;
                p=2;
                continue;
            }
            else{
                primes[number]=testnumber;
                number++;
                p=2;
            } 
        }
        if(sqrprime<max){
            n++;
            l=n;    
            sqrprime = primes[n]*primes[n];
            }
        if(sqrprime== max)
            break;
    }
}


 main(){
       //im using the prime_array_generator here 
    }
```

the program showing results till `max = 10^6` not working after that

Comment: You run out of space after the 100 000th prime.

Comment: BTW, I tried running your code ... not sure if what you're using was cut-and-pasted here, but this code doesn't produce the correct output.  Here is a corrected version with debug output (note that IDEONE limits the output size): http://ideone.com/clone/BmwZgG

Answer (score 4):

Your prime array

```
long primes[100000];
```

has only space for the primes to 1299709, after that, you are writing outside the array bounds.

There are 50847534 primes below 10^9.

Aside: Your algorithm isn't efficient, for a target bound of 10^9, you should definitely use a sieve.

Simple and efficient is the [Sieve of Eratosthenes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_eratosthenes)